# How do you make website for both web crawlers and single page application users?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, search-engine, single-page-application

I'm going to be very specific.

I have a frontend...
http://www.eroticahub.site (not porn)

If you have javascript, it becomes... http://www.eroticahub.site/#!body=home [renders with jquery/ajax load]

If you don't have javascript, it remains... 
http://www.eroticahub.site/

Then you click "Privacy" at the bottom.

If you have javascript, it loads the file /body/privacy.html into the main div and you get... 
http://www.eroticahub.site/#!body=privacy [renders with jquery/ajax load]

If you don't have javascript, you just get... http://www.eroticahub.site/body/privacy_body.html

^ I'm just fetching the file that jquery/ajax is inserting into the template.

This isn't a very good solution. I want a page that never does a full refresh/reload but that is fully indexed by every major search engine.

Is it perhaps possible to make a command like this:

```
For each link in page, 
  if ( user_has_javascript )
    return page_with_javascript;
  else
    return serverside_render( page_with_javascript );
```

That way any user who doesn't have javascript (web crawlers included) will get a pure html/css version of the page. I'm planning on using Ruby for my backend. Does anyone have a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: You can detect if it's the crawler by User-Agent, or use <noscript> in html.

Comment: So let's say a user goes straight to... http://www.eroticahub.site/privacy . It would have the generic site templace and then inside that there would be a noscript that contains the privacy body template. And then at the bottom there would be a javascript that says something like "If URL == privacy" then run this javascript that uses jquery/ajax to load the privacy body statement. Then if a user clicks a link to go to "legal"... you can't re-load the generic site template because that would cause a page refresh.

Comment: You can't generate different html depending on the crawler user agent because that would smell like cheating to a search engine. Those things are stupid.

Comment: Okay. Let's say a user goes straight to... eroticahub.site/#privacy . Search engines understand URL parameters but often ignore fragments, so the #privacy probably won't appear in a search engine listing because it is a fragment.

Comment: Okay. Let's say a user goes straight to... eroticahub.site/privacy and then they click a link to go to eroticahub.site/legal . The link to legal will have a javascript function that takes the user to eroticahub.site/legal#dynamic . If the #dynamic is there, then load the "legal" template into the body. If it isn't there, there must be a <noscript> and the backend must inject the "legal" body into the noscript.

Comment: So like <a href=eroticahub.site/legal onclick=function(){addHash("dynamic")}> Link </a>

Comment: This would work because the only way to possibly get to a page with #dynamic in it is if your browser supports javascript. So #dynamic could let the page know that you got to that page via javascript and so the client knows that if the page isn't the homepage and it contains the #dynamic, call the function to load the HTML without contacting the server. And if the server gets a request with #dynamic in it, it could just return the exact same HTML/CSS/Javascript as it would if the #dynamic were not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make everything work with regular URLs and no JavaScript. You want your JS to be [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), so build it on top of a working, plain HTML + server side solution.

Next write JavaScript that fetches the data it needs from the server
and updates the document to match another of the pages.

That JavaScript should use [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) to change the URL to match the URL of the page from the server that you are generating locally with JavaScript.

*NB: `pushState` replaces hashbang URIs. It is a standard designed for the use case you described (while hashbangs were an [ugly hack](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)).*

Bind that JavaScript to your link click / form submit / etc event.

Add a [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for a [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_popstate_event) so that when the user clicks *Back* you can restore the page to it's previous state.

Comment: So doing it this way, I should keep the javascript out of the html because that would be "unobtrusive". No javascript in the html [except for a link to a fill with all the javascript]

Comment: And then on pop state, I would just do "history.back();"

Comment: @MichaelLafayette — No. `history.back()` is how you send people back in the history. The popstate event fires when the user chooses to go back in the history. At the point you use JS to change the back page to its previous state with DOM manipulation.

Comment: Oh. So if I just use pushState to change the url to match the URL from the server and then I click back, it won't go back without me setting window.onpopstate. Just set window.onpopstate like so... window.onpopstate = function(event) { loadOldState() }; where  loadOldState gets the state from the event and uses jquery/ajax to load the html from the old page in. How exactly do you get the old URL from the event object and do this last part?

Comment: $(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;
} . Is the old url in this state variable?

Comment: No, the old URL is in `location` (because the browser just went back to it). The state will be the state that you specified when you called `pushState`.

Comment: Oh. window.location will contain the old url. No need to do location.replace

Comment: What happens if I have a search bar form where the form template is created in the Ruby backend? Is there any way to get around a full page refresh for submitting a search and getting back and rendering the list of search results? [no framework]

Comment: Oh nevermind - I think I can pass the search parameters in a jquery ajax load.

Comment: Do you know what framework would be good for building a simple SPA on top of a series of static web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Let's say a user goes straight to... eroticahub.site/privacy and then they click a link to go to eroticahub.site/legal The link looks like this:

```
<a href=eroticahub.site/legal.html onclick=function(){window.location.hash = 'legal.html';return false;}> 
    Link 
</a>
```

So if the user has no javascript, they go to eroticahub.site/legal.html and request a whole new page from the server and if they do have javascript they go to eroticahub.site#legal.html and will not request a whole new page from the server.

The # will trigger a hash change event which will call a function with a big switch statement that will contain (window.location.hash === "legal.html") in it. This condition will trigger the loading of the snippets/legal.html html into the web page using jquery/ajax.

If the link goes to eroticahub.site/legal.html, the backend will deliver the same template it did for eroticahub.site/privacy.html, but with a different middle section containing words from snippets/privacy.html

If the user has javascript, the middle section is rendered the same as if the user does not have javascript. It is only when the user clicks a link that the distinction must be made whether or not they have javascript. The AJAX would have to load the dynamic content (#legal) on top of [replacing] the static content in the content div of eroticahub.site/privacy and then this would in tern be replaced by more html in the exact same div. A convention would have to be maintained such that:

```
<a href=eroticahub.site/legal.html onclick=function(){window.location.hash = 'legal.html';return false;}> 
    Link 
</a>

<a href=eroticahub.site/privacy.html onclick=function(){window.location.hash = 'privacy.html';return false;}> 
    Link 
</a>

<a href=eroticahub.site/user_content/stories.html onclick=function(){window.location.hash = 'user_content/stories.html';return false;}> 
    Link 
</a>
```

etc.

Comment: A consequence of this is that the ID of the snipper being put in and the ID of the snipper that is replacing it should be the same.